# Finding the last non-zero value in a given row in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have 10 rows of data of the following form:

```
00004
04000
03000
06000
00500
00001
```

What I'd like to be able to do is get the last non-zero value in each of these rows and return them beside their respective rows like so:

```
000044
040004
030303
066006
055005
002011
```

Note that each value above is in a separate cell. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: When you say rows.  Is each number in each row in the same cell in that row or are they in different cells?

Comment: @ScottCraner Sorry, each is in a different cell, updated to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

You can use chained formulas, to first replace all '0' by nothing, and then take the rightmost character, like
`=RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(cell1&cell2&cell3...,"0",""),1)`

Comment: Sorry, updated the question to clarify that each value is in a different cell.

Comment: FWIW: if OP has Office 365 Excel then `=RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,A1:E1),"0",""),1)`

Comment: Or  better still `=RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(CONCAT(A1:E1),"0",""),1)`

Answer (score 1):

Use the following array formula:

```
=INDEX(A1:E1,MATCH(2,IF(A1:E1<>0,1)))
```

Being ans array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter when exiting edit mode instead of Enter.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]

Comment: I'm a bit mystified. Isn't the first argument to the `MATCH` function the value that you're trying to find? Why would that be `2`?

Answer (score 1):

With your data in A1:E1 (and assuming all values are integers), you can use this normally entered formula:

```
F1: =LOOKUP(2,1/A1:E1,A1:E1)
```

and fill down.

If the LOOKUP function can't find the lookup_value, the function matches the largest value in lookup_vector that is less than or equal to lookup_value. `1/a1:e1` will always return a value less than 2, or a `DIV/0` error.  So the function will return the last non-zero value, or, if they are all zero's, an `NA` error.

[image]